# Skin Color Detection using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

How to detect the **colour of the skin** using OpenCV?

What about using OpenCV **Haar face detector** to find a face region and then getting the **average or most common color** in that face region, since it should be the skin color?

Update:

**Environment:** My frames will have the facial features. (only From hair to shoulders, as attached)

[image]

Comment: Some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207916/how-to-perform-skin-tone-matching/17208493#17208493

Comment: Look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294425/skin-detection-with-gaussian-mixture-models

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with little more information.

Comment: PhDs are made with this title. You wont find a DIRECT answer here i think

Comment: Any inputs on "What about using OpenCV Haar face detector to find a face region and then getting the average or most common color in that face region, since it should be the skin color?"

Comment: It's worth a shot, but you are unlikely to get an answer saying "this will definitely work." Try it, and if it doesn't work, try another method.

Comment: you can also look at [camshift](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_3/sidebar.html)

Comment: @samkhan13 Any ideas how to achieve the skin color detection in iOS

Comment: @pkc456 sorry, i don't have any experience with iOS, swift and c# if you want to implement opencv or specifically camshit i would suggest you start here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html and https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you really don't need HAAR detection. the following will definitely work...

my answer for this and similar issues involving color based detection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375222/1463143

what it was originally inspired from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756351/1463143

if the codes end up detecting blond or brown hair along with the skin, try changing `min_YCrCb` to (80,133,77) or play around with that min value

here is a [video showcasing skin detection](http://youtu.be/yKVMbwA9y2E) using above mentioned technique.

:)