# Real time tracking of hand

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to detect and track hand in real time using opencv. I thought haar cascade classifiers would yield a fair result. After training with 10k and 20k positive and negative images respectively, I obtained a classifier xml file. Unfortunately, it detects hand only in certain positions, proving that it works best only for rigid objects. So I am now thinking of adopting another algorithm that can track hand, once detected through haar classifier.

My question is,if I make sure that haar classifier detects hand in a certain frame, certain position, what method would yield robust tracking of hand further?

I searched web a bit, and have understood I can go for optical flow of the detected hand , or kalman filter or particle filter, but also have come across their own disadvantages.

also, If I incorporate stereo vision, would it help me, as I can possibly reconstruct hand in 3d.

Comment: You can try hierarchical chamfer matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concluded rightly about Haar features - they aren't that useful when it comes to non-rigid objects.

Take a look at the following papers which use skin colour to detect hands.

1. [Interaction between hands and wearable cameras](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/ActiveVision/Papers/mayol_etal_bmvc2004/mayol_etal_bmvc2004.pdf)
2. [Markerless inspection of augmented reality objects](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/pubs/Lee-2007-ISWC.pdf)

and this paper that uses KLT features to track the hand after the first detection:

[Fast 2D hand tracking with flocks of features and multi-cue integration](http://nguyendangbinh.org/Proceedings/CVPR/2004/DATA/RTV4HCI_09.PDF)

I would say that a stereo camera will not help your cause much, as 3D reconstruction of non-rigid objects isn't straightforward and would require a whole lot of innovation and development. However, you can take a look at the papers in the hand pose estimation section of [this page](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~bdrs2/research.html) if you wish to pursue 3D tracking.

EDIT: Also take a look at [this recent paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kkitani/pdf/LK-CVPR13.pdf), which seems to get good results.

Comment: third link is broken.

Comment: Updated with another link. Citeseer servers sometimes misbehave.

Comment: The last link was broken i.e., recent paper link.

Answer (score 1):

Zhang et al.'s [Real-time Compressive Tracking](http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~cslzhang/CT/CT.htm) does a reasonable job of tracking an object, once it has been detected by some other method, provided that the motion is not too fast. They have an OpenCV implementation (but it would need a bit of work to reuse).

Answer (score 0):

This [research paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rywang/6dhands/gloveless_tracking.pdf) describes a method to track hands, without using gloves by using a stereo camera setup.

Comment: This seems to work for a noiseless background. I have a noisy background,

Comment: It uses the skin-color for the segmentation. The author of the paper also has a company, that uses a kinect for the handtracking. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

there have been similar questions on stack overflow...

have a look at my answer and that of others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375647/1463143

you can for certain get better results by avoiding haar training and detection for deformable entities.

Comment: My background contains wood, I can't use any skin detection algorithm.

Comment: @ria15 try out the algorithm and see to what extent it works. using simple foreground/background separation you can run the given code on the foreground image.

Answer (score 0):

CamShift algorithm is generally fast and accurate, if you want to track the hand as a single entity. OpenCV documentation contains a good, easy-to-understand demo program that you can easily modify.

If you need to track fingers etc., however, further modeling will be needed.

Comment: My background contains wood, so as camshift is based on color histograms, it won't help me.

Comment: You might want to use optical flow followed by some kind of shape matching, then. This will be not that easy with a moving background, but there is a higher chance to track a hand under some assumptions (size, etc).