# Tracking hands with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

Currently I am working on a project where I should be able to track the position of a hand (2d). Just the position, there is no need for "gestures" or vinger tracking.

Now I have it working with Haar Cascade tracking, but this only works for "my fist" (the haarcascade file is for a fist). And not for any other "form" (e.g open, side) your hand could be.

What is the best way to go about with this? I don't think creating an haarcascade file for every possible "position" of a hand is the solution here.

Comment: u just need to track. U don't try mean shift

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand your answer. I only need the position of the hands. (e.g) the center (or something close to it) of each hand.

Comment: While not quite giving the full answer, following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17721997/2419207 and articles http://s-ln.in/2013/04/18/hand-tracking-and-gesture-detection-opencv/ and http://simena86.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/hand-tracking-and-recognition-with-opencv/ give be useful as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Something simpler might work better.

I would try color segmentation and then find contours and get the centre of the largest blob.

For the color segmentation I would use hsi or yuv color spaces, ignoring the intensity component. For example setting min and max thresholds for the hue and saturation channels.